# insomnia error: using tabs can lead to unpredictable results

Tags: insomnia

i have documentation api that using insomnia designer and in the last 12000 lines i hadnt error like this

[image: insomnia error: using tabs can lead to unpredictable results]

in all jsons as body or result this error may occurred

```
  requestBody:
    content:
      application/json:
        schema:      # Request body contents
          type: object
          example:
            {   
              "type": "national_card",
              "data": "",
              "mimetype": "image/jpeg"
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case just need to remote a space here

[image]